# What's correct here, "will" or "am going to"?

Tags: future-tense, future-time, will-vs-going-to

As an English learner, I've got a question regarding the following sentence.

"I've got a 10% pay raise. Next month, I ... have 2750 pounds."

Should I use "will" or "am going to" here? And why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Either is fine. They are completely interchangeable.

(American English speaker)

Answer (score 0):

You could use *am going to*, but *shall* is better than *will*. *I will* has the sense of *I am determined to.*